# c++ while loop won't exit once condition is met

Tags: c++, while-loop, ifstream

I'm trying to use a while loop to ensure a file has been opened with "ifstream inputFile(fileName);".  If I enter a correct file name first, the while loop condition (!inputFile) correctly evaluates to false, and is skipped.  If I enter a bad file name, the while loop correctly evaluates to true and is entered.  Inside the while loop, if I enter a correct file name, the value of inputFile does change from 0 to 1 (I check with a cout statement) - but the while loop doesn't stop.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
   string fileName;

   cout << "\nEnter a file name: ";
   cin >> fileName;

   ifstream inputFile(fileName);

   while(!inputFile) {
      cout << "File not found, please enter another file: ";
      cin >> fileName;    
      ifstream inputFile(fileName);

      // just added to check values
      cout << "fileName is: " << fileName << endl;
      cout << "inputFile is: " << inputFile << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: You declared two different `inputFile` objects. One has absolutely nothing to do with the other. Once the first object is in failed state, it will remain in a failed state. Declaring another object, with the same name, and using it to open the file succesfully does absolutely nothing to change the first object's failed state.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand my error now.

Answer (score 1):

The probleme here is that you define 2 variables `inputFile` in two different scopes. The first one is evaluated in the while condition, the second one is created and destroyed at every while iteration, and never evaluated.

Consider trying:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
   string fileName;

   cout << "\nEnter a file name: ";
   cin >> fileName;

   ifstream inputFile(fileName);

   while(!inputFile) {
      cout << "File not found, please enter another file: ";
      cin >> fileName;    
      inputFile.open(fileName); // <== Here is the change

      // just added to check values
      cout << "fileName is: " << fileName << endl;
      cout << "inputFile is: " << inputFile << endl;
   }
}
```